# Как хранить список данных в ASP.Net WepAPI Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Реализую веб-сервис WebAPI на ASP.NET Core.

Мне необходимо хранить список следующего класса:

```
public class Entity
{
/// <summary>
/// ИД, который нужно хранить.
/// </summary>
[Key]
public int Id { get; private set; }

/// <summary>
/// Токен, который нужно хранить.
/// </summary>
private CancellationTokenSource Token { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Ссылка на кастомный класс, который не нужно хранить.
/// </summary>
private Reporter Reporter;

/// <summary>
/// Конструктор.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">ИД.</param>
public Entity(int id)
{
}

/// <summary>
/// Ассинхронный метод какой-то.
/// </summary>
public async Task<byte[]> AsyncMethod1()
{
}

/// <summary>
/// Ассинхронный метод какой-то.
/// </summary>
public async Task<byte[]> AsyncMethod2(CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken)
{
}

/// <summary>
/// Метод какой-то.
/// </summary>
public void Method1()
{
}


}
```

Как правильно реализовать хранения списка Entity в ASP.NET Core WebAPI, чтобы к нему могли обращаться все контроллеры?

Comment: В базе данных? Опишите подробнее, должен ли этот список сохраняться в случае падения/перезагрузки сервиса.

Comment: Да, необходимо сохранять в БД (желательно в EF(Entity Framework)). MemoryCache не подойдет. При попытке сохранить данную модель в БД EF столкнулся с проблемой сохранения классов Net в БД. Критично сохранять свойство Token с типом данных CancellationTokenSource (или CancellationToken). Как реализовать сохранение сущности с таким типом данных в EF? Или же тут не получится сохранять через EF.

Comment: @Russo вы точно идете неправильным путем. Зачем вам хранить `CancellationTokenSource` в базе данных?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko А где тогда еще можно хранить CancellationTokenSource? Мне необходим этот токен, чтобы остановить задачу(Task) через token.Cancel(), запущенную по этому токену

Comment: @Russo как обычно - в оперативной памяти. Он ведь полезен только в пределах времени работы приложения. После остановки приложения смысла от него уже нет

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Да, по идее как ты и сказал, мне нужно хранить словарь токенов (Dirctiory<Id, Token>) как глобальную переменную, чтобы при различных запросах (get и post), можно было добавлять новые токены и использовать существующие в словаре. Как правильно это реализовать? (Был бы благодарен за ссылку на пример или способ реализации)

Comment: @Russo вам нужно реализовать хранение вашего словаря используя "синглтон" (англ. Singleton). Как это сделать наиболее правильно - я не смогу подсказать, поскольку пока не приходилось решать подобную задачу. Вам больше помогут другие авторы. Дополните вопрос информацией из вашего предыдущего комментария, и вам помогут

Comment: @Russo в поисковике можно искать по запросу "Singleton c# implementation". Например, первое, что выдает, уже будет полезно: [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://espressocoder.com/2019/01/03/implementing-the-singleton-pattern-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: [Ошибка XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/184217).

Answer (score 0):

Добавить класс, в котором будет необходимый список, добавить в конфигурацию сервиса зависимость через services.AddSingleton, а в конструкторе контроллера, который должен обращаться к этому списку, прокидывать это класс. Тогда все необходимые контроллеры будут иметь доступ к одному единственному списку